# In STS when clicking on used AutoCompletionComboBox getting the source not found in Class File editor

Tags: java, debugging

I have checked the path from other folder .it is correctly pointing but still getting the error

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the jar which you are using is source jar file.

You can download the source-jar files from maven repository for the same version (Note: Even different version of source jar supports).
Then just give source jar file location then it will open related class for the same.
[image]